# HP laptop keeps rebooting

Tags: windows-xp, laptop

One of my user's hp laptop, keeps rebooting, it gets to the XP screen and reboots, I tried booting it in the Safe Mode, the same thing happened, tried it to load last good known configuration, all leads to the same thing.  Tried going through the Windows XP Repair (executed **scan disk** and **disable intelppm**) to no luck.

Any suggestions on what I can do next, besides re-installing Windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable automatic restart on system failure (one of the options in the F8 menu) and report back on what bluescreen is appearing.  We can go from there.  Also follow Jikag's post advice and do some hardware diagnostics.

Comment: SYSTEM_LICENSE_VIOLATION

Comment: SYSTEM_LICENSE_VIOLATION with 0_0... followed by 9A, 5, 13D4, 4 & 2

Comment: Per: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559317(v=vs.85).aspx
and: https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+xp+system+license+violation&aq=0&oq=windows+xp+System_lic&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=windows+xp+system_license_violation&oq=windows+xp+system_license_violation&gs_l=serp.3..0i30j0i8.19605.23218.0.23471.4.4.0.0.0.0.175.482.1j3.4.0.les%3Bcesh..0.0...1.1.KjfnXtwAh68&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=80ef5323c76d6b79&bpcl=35466521&biw=1588&bih=807
It looks like your best bet is repair install, or complete wipe.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up reformatting the HDD.  Thank goodness for LiveCDs, I was able to get data out too.

Comment: Good to hear George.  Sorry you had to reformat, but im glad you got your data at least.  Thanks for the Rep!

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure the hardware is good.
Get a boot CD like [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html) or [Hiren's](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) and do a test on the Hard Drive, the RAM and the CPU, in that order.

Comment: Thank you for you help.  It was very useful and helpful, but francisswest actually helped me, so I will give him the answer and I'll upvote you!  Thanks!